# Can XML files be read quickly using pure C?

Tags: c, xml, opencv, face-detection, viola-jones

I am designing a face detection system using pure C. I don't wanna go though too much trouble of coding the training algorithm in C when it is easily available in openCV for Viola-Jones and LBP. However, i noticed that in openCV the training data is stored in XML files. I am planning to run the detector on a TI development board and also use the DSP in the board. The board is running an ubuntu OS so it has a file system but am trying to make the detector work as fast as possible and I don't want the accessing of the training data to affect my detector speed. So is it a good idea to proceed with XML files? Or is there a way to convert these files to CSV which I think is easier to read from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org)

Comment: Can the XML files in OpenCV which contains a trained cascade of classifiers be read and ported with C? Despite being very big and complex? Am having a difficulty of getting a grasp of parsing XML in C